# python for UPnp- Compatible with windows

Tags: python, windows, frameworks, upnp

Please advice me some framework that can be run on windows with linux commands. I can install the framework with linux commands, so i need some framework where I can write protocols for UPnP. I want to write protocols in python and Python-Brisa supports only LINUX commands to install it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834439/python-for-upnp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834518/perl-python-for-upnp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788963/upnp-device-with-python

Comment: @thkala I don't think the duplicate complaint is valid. None of these questions have been answered.

Comment: @Rafe: Actually I was referring to the fact that they may all have the same source. Since I cannot prove this way or the other, I simply mentioned them and did not vote to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a Linux-like environment in your windows, look into [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: I am trying to do it...lets c...plz check my next reply to this thread....i may need your help again

Comment: I have installed Cygwin but now I am trying to install the python-brisa but it is not letting me to do it.I put the Python-brisa in the home directory and run the command - cd python-brisa....it says -no such file or directory. I dO PWD in unix to know my current location. How do i do it here??

Comment: @user You have to create a directory before you can cd to it. So `mkdir python-brisa`.

Comment: no, actually, I have a folder on my desktop- python-brisa. I has a setup.py file in it.Once I go into the folder, i want to use the command-sudo python setup.py install. but i dont know how to make it happen.Right now, I am into Home/user directory. If I do mkdir python-brisa , it will change into home/user/python-brisa. But still my files are not into the folder. Do I need some filezilla software to tranfer my files in to linux environment??

Comment: @user597293 if you `cd /` and then `ls` you'll see a folder called `cygdrive` -- that folder contains your Windows drives

Comment: i found the path.....now i can see my file into the folder. But it is not taking teh Sudo command. It should accept this command as it is a linux command.

Comment: @user597293 `sudo` is not necessary for cygwin